# What logical operator will return false only if both statements are false?

Tags: javascript, logic

What logical operator will return the following result?

```
If A is true, and B is false, return True
If A is true, and B is True, return True
If A is false and B is true, return True
If A is false and B is false return false
```

Comment: This should be extremely easy to figure out -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8y7xjfqk/**

Comment: Basic logic. It's a logical OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the OR operator, in logic known as [logical disjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)

In most programming languages it can either be a written word (`or`) or a symbol like this:

```
||
```

So (in javascript) you need

```
A || B
```

Here's a truth table:

```
A | B | A or B
0 | 0 |   0
0 | 1 |   1
1 | 0 |   1
1 | 1 |   1
```

Answer (score 0):

The logical OR operator - in JavaScript, this is the `||` operator.